# SSL certificate error in solr

Tags: ssl, solr

Failed to get system information from https://localhost:8443/solr/ due to: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: certificate for localhost doesn't match any of the subject alternatives name. [example1.host.com, example.host2.com, example3.host3.com]

```
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:164)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier.verify(BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier.java:61)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:140)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:114)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.verifyHostname(SSLSocketFactory.java:569)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:544)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:409)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:882)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:220)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:164)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:139)
at org.apache.solr.util.SolrCLI.getJson(SolrCLI.java:527)
at org.apache.solr.util.SolrCLI.getJson(SolrCLI.java:471)
at org.apache.solr.util.SolrCLI$StatusTool.runTool(SolrCLI.java:659)
at org.apache.solr.util.SolrCLI.main(SolrCLI.java:215)
```

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this?

Answer (score 2):

In your solr.in file activate the

**`REM set SOLR_HOST=`**

line and set your host name to a value that matches 1/SANs